# PHP Text Box Length

Tags: html

I'm playing with some PHP for my website. How do I set the length of a text box that the user types in? Also, what is the code for making multiple line text boxes?

Thanks.

Comment: So with the <textarea> part of it, I need to line it up on the same line of html to other <input> boxes. But it needs to line up along the top, any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you really want to specify this in the HTML code as the `maxlength` attribute in the text box.

```
<input type="text" size="25" maxlength="25" value="Enter your name here!">
```

As for multilines, you want to set up a text area instead of a text box.

```
<textarea name="comments">
</textarea>
```

The `size` refers to the physical size of the box, where as the `maxlength` refers to the input data length.

Again, not PHP, but HTML.

As with all input, you should verify in your script that you are getting the length you expected.

Comment: Note that you should check the length of the input in PHP even though you define maxlength. Since there are ways around it.

Comment: Very true, I shouldn't have assumed that people wouldn't validate their input.

Answer (score 1):

The length of a textbox is done with CSS rules or with the size attribute of the  tag.

ex. `<input name="text" size="200" />`

A multiple line text box is a `<textarea></textarea>` HTML tag.

Neither of these have anything to do with PHP, but rather are simple HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred method of specifying a "size" (i.e. character width) of an input box is to use the `width` CSS property:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" style="width: 42em;" />

/* CSS */
#search {
    width: 42em;
}
```

Multi-line text boxes are called *text areas* in HTML and the `<textarea>` element represents them, as the other answers state.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer to mention using CSS for dimensions

Answer (score 0):

In html use a `<input type="text" size="25" maxlength="100">` for a single-line text field, and `<textarea></textarea>` for multiple-line text boxes.  `size="25"` determines the number of characters that will be visible in the text field (in this case 25), and `maxlength="100"` determines the maximum number of characters that a user can input into that field (in this case 100).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_textarea.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_input.asp

> So with the  part of it, I need to line it up on the same line of html to other  boxes. But it needs to line up along the top, any suggestions for that?

Not sure I understand, maybe you could show some code that illustrates the problem.

I recommend to install the Web developer add-on for firefox, that way you can edit css directly and see the results! https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60